# Why doesn't bootstrap automatically change the highlight on the active tab?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using bootstraps tab feature as follows:

```
<div class="tabBar container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pick a Quiz</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#">History</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#">Philosophy</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#">Science</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#leaderboards" role="tab">Leaderboards</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#login">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If one of the tabs has the "active" class, then it is highlighted. However when clicking on a new tab the highlight doesn't change, and only the initial active tab has the highlight (in my case, the "About" tab).

1. Is there a way using bootstrap to change the highlight to whichever is actually active? and...
2. If not, is there an easier alternative than using jQuery to add and remove the active class on the corresponding tabs when another is clicked, which seems to involve adding unique ID's to each tab and adding a jQuery click event for each one, i.e:

   ```
     $('#tab2').click(function() {
       $(this).addClass('active');
       $('#tab1').removeClass('active');
     });

     $('#tab3').click(function() {
       $(this).addClass('active');
       $('#tab1').removeClass('active');
       $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
     });
   ```

etc. etc.

Comment: Have you checked this code on its own? When I paste it (not the JS) into Bootply everything seems to function as expected; `active` is applied to the current tab and removed from previous.

Comment: You're combining tabs with dropdowns, I'm not sure that's a supported configuration. It's a little confusing UI to say the least.

Comment: @RobertC - I've tried the code on its own using chrome and firefox, and the highlight does not change.

Comment: @DavidG - the UI with the inclusion of the dropdown menu is pretty much copied from the bootstrap website (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#tabs)

Comment: https://www.bootply.com/ZXMKZDI9yT ... tested on macOS Safari, Chrome, Firefox. In each instance the active class moves to the most recently clicked tab.  I cannot replicate the error you claim is happening, even if I drop down to v4-alpha.

Comment: thanks for your input, I'll scour my script and try to figure out what's causing the issue